# Android Studio's Image Asset Studio won't recognize png file in file system

Tags: android, android-studio, assets, missing-data

I have a png file named triedsohardicon.png I want to use for my app's launcher icon, but after putting it in the folder associated with the project, I find that Image Asset Studio doesn't show any triedsohardicon.png in its file system browser in that location.

In addition, if I put the line
android:icon="@drawable/triedsohardicon"
in AndroidManifest.xml (because I did in fact put the png file in the TriedSoHard/app/src/main/res/drawable folder), the text in quotes just returns the error "Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/triedsohardicon'".

The png has dimensions 512x512. I could use some help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launcher Icon should be placed in **mipmap** `res\mipmap\triedsohardicon.png`

Place your launcher Icon through Image Asset like below:

[image]

Upload and Save the png and it will be placed in mipmap automatically.

In **Maifest**:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/triedsohardicon"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello there! I don't seem to have a mipmap folder in res, but quite a few folders named mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, and the like. Should I create a new folder named mipmap? If not, which one should I put the png file in?

Comment: Put it through Image asset or put different sizes in every mipmap-dpi folder accordingly. For this moment you can add in any mipmap folder and it will work.

Comment: The image asset browser doesn't find anything but ic_launcher.png in mipmap-hdpi, where I put triedsohardicon.png. I tried synchronizing the project but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you add android:icon="@mipmap/triedsohardicon" in your manifest under application tag ?

Comment: I hadn't before, but I just changed AndroidManifest.xml to have:
android:icon="@mipmap/triedsohardicon"
and it still doesn't show up in the Image Asset browser.

Comment: Why you have to go to image asset ? If you run your app now you will see your icon has been changed.

Comment: I meant I didn't have android:icon="@mipmap/triedsohardicon" in when I tried putting the png file in a mipmap folder. Before this, I had android:icon="@mipmap/triedsohardicon" at one point, which gave me the error mentioned in my original post. It still gives me this error.

EDIT: Oof, sorry to be confusing. Before I had android:icon="@drawable/triedsohardicon", now I have android:icon="@mipmap/triedsohardicon". Same error. Thought I should clarify.

Comment: You mean, You put triedsohardicon.png in mimmap-hdpi folder, then set android:icon="@mipmap/triedsohardicon". But still showing : Cannot resolve triedsohardicon error ?

Comment: That's correct. When I hover over the line in AndroidManifest.xml that's the error it gives.

Here's two screenshots, one for this error, one for the Image Asset one:
http://imgur.com/a/vI6ey

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation. Thats strange. It supposed be a simple task. 1) Try rebuilding\clean\re-open project. If those doesn't work, 2) remove the triedsohardicon from mipmap. Open Image asset upload it from your device location (ex: download) and finish generating icon. 3) Try putting triedsohardicon to all the mipmap folders 4) create a mimmap folder in res then add triedsohardicon.png there. Hope either of this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Just for reference, 1) didn't work, but 2) did: Once I uploaded the png file from my Desktop, the Image Asset browser was able to find it and subsequently copy it to all the mipmap folders. Subsequently the error from AndroidManifest.xml became resolved. I didn't try the others. I guess I don't need to move my assets into any Android Studio folders from now on.

Comment: Yeah, 2) is very handy. It generates icons for different  screen-size automatically. Glad you solved your problem. If the answer helped you can mark it as an accepted answer.